# Parse resquest Payload to Object

Tags: spring, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin/ Java World. So I need a little help to parse an old fashion request in an easy way.

My controller was working perfectly before the new Request.

MyController:

```
@PostMapping("/create")
@ResponseStatus(OK)
fun create(
    @RequestBody @NotEmpty request: PersonRequest,
) = service.create(mapper.toDto(request))
```

New BodyRequest:

```
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "id": "name",
            "value": "blablabla"
        },
        {
            "id": "phone",
            "value": "+1 11111111"
        },
        {
            "id": "birthday",
            "value": "2000-01-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Class:

```
class PersonRequest(

        var name: String?,

        @field: Pattern(regexp = "blabla") 
        var phone: String?,

        var birthday: LocalDate?
    )
```

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request body you posted doesn't match the class `PersonRequest`.

Change the request body structure to:

```
{
  "name": "blablabla",
  "phone": "+1 11111111",
  "birthday": "2000-01-01"
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Since you can't update the request structure, your other option is to change the class structure by creating two classes as below:

```
class PersonRequest(var fields: List<Field>)

class Field(var id: String, var value:Any)
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The last step, which is optional based on your requirement, is that you can manipulate the `PersonRequest` class now and convert it to any other class using normal setters/getters.

**UPDATE 3:**

To convert the `List<Field>` to `PersonRequest`, you could do it like this:

```
val personRequest = PersonRequest()
fields.forEach {
  when(it.id) {
    "name" -> personRequest.name = it.value
    "phone" -> personRequest.phone = it.value
    "birthday" -> personRequest.birthday = it.value
  }
}
```

Not the neatest of codes, but...

Comment: I can not Change the request body structure

Comment: Everything you said make sense, I've thought about it before the post. Maybe I was not so clear with my question. The biggest deal for me is map the object with list<field> to an object with variables.

Comment: @Luiz.brsp I see, it's a different question now. I updated my answer again